# XSP/Mono: preventing "Warning as Error" exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, mono, xsp

I'm running an ASP.NET v4.8 project under Mono.
Actually, I'm doing it by using the Mono's standalone web server - XSP.

When I try to start the application in browser, I'm getting this annoying exception:
***System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException:**
error CS1685: Warning as Error: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from` mscorlib.dll'"*

[image]

For each project in my solution, I set the "Treat warnings as errors" option to "None" - but it still doesn't work.
I suspect that the "Warning as Error" exceptions come from the XSP program, but not sure.

I can say that I able to load the application when I'm deleting 2 files - System.Memory.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll which both are used by npgsql.dll.
But when I try to use Postgres in the application, I'm getting another exception which says that the 2 files are missing...

Since the project works fine on IIS, my question is:
how do I stop those annoying "Warning as Error" exceptions?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: "the project works fine on IIS" is meaningless here. If you use .NET Framework, then you should stay with Windows/IIS. Mono is going away fast, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/